# How to reduce apache http response header size while 304 Not Modified

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

When i am requesting a page which is already loaded, and checking in firebug inspector

i get

```
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

> **Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 23 Oct 2012 09:28:57 GMT
ETag:"200000000296d-12ca-4cca274ac8a98"
Expires:Tue, 30 Oct 2012 09:28:57 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

My doubt is .. is there any way in which i can reduce the response headers passed over from the server to browser when a page is not modified.

like in one reference website, on inspecting with firebug i could find:

> **Response Headers**

```
Date:Tue, 23 Oct 2012 09:28:56 GMT
Etag:"79ee2bbda49fcd1:0"
```

with 2 values. Please provide me with some helpful resource.
Correct me if i am wrong some where? Thanks for help.

This reference website is hosted on iis. and the longer response iam geting on apache.

> **UPDATE:**

Upon googling i got to this url.
https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.2.x/modules/http/http_filters.c#L1281
reading the code, tells me it is filtering header fields if its a HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED type od response. Is this module default installed in apache? or how to get this installed on my apache and get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on those headers your Browser "Knows what to do" with that page...

You may hide your server information "Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13".
But users browser need other lines to proccess correctly that page.

Comment: The first time i load the page without cache, it has many values. Afterwards when i load,it has 2 entries. Even i dont know how its done.